# What are the short commands of Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Code and I like to navigate one class to  another through keyboard,because i used Visual Studio so it has become my habit to use Keyboard instead of mouse.I know it shows short command in menu but there is no such command for navigating one class to another.So please if someone have any idea about the short commands.I shall be very thankful to you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Google it at least?

My first hit on "XCode 4 shortcuts" is a nice PDF with all shortcuts

here is the 2nd hit:

> http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html

The new [XCode 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Orientation/Orientation.html) has a lot of changes, but if you Google a bit, you don't need to ask a non-programming question in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The standard link to provide is [this one](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf).

The specific combinations you probably want are command+shift+o for "fast open" (into which you can type a class name rather than a file name if you prefer), and command+control+cursors to switch between implementation and interface and back and forth through your recently opened history. Another good one is option-clicking and option+return where you're using the keyboard to open a file in the assistant pane instead of the main one.